# Using C++ rand() to get random directions (up/down/left/right) - always getting up

Tags: c++, random, console, srand

I'm making a C++ text-based Battleship game. I use the rand() function to randomly place the computer's ships. I seed the number generator *once* at the beginning of main(), with the line below:

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0)));
```

I later use the rand() function to choose the spaces where each individual ship will go. (The coordinates where one end of the ship will start). I then use rand() in the function below, which decides the direction in which they will extend (depending on the ship's length):

```
char randDirection()
{
    int randNumber = rand();
    int x = (randNumber % 4) + 1;

    if (x = 1)
        return 'u';
    else if (x = 2)
        return 'd';
    else if (x = 3)
        return 'l';
    else
        return 'r';
}
```

It randomly gets a number between 1 and 4, and returns a direction (represented by a char) depending on the number. While I had success with randomly choosing the locations for the pieces, **this function always sets the pieces vertically. They always go up. Can anyone tell me why?**

Comment: `if (x = 1)` Please turn on compiler warnings. This is an assignment, not a comparison. Your compiler should warn you about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is on every "if", you're doing an assignation, not a test.
Moreover, in a test an assignation will always return the result of the assignation.
For example:

`if (x = 0)
   // will never be here because 0 is false in a test
 else if (x = 42)
   // will always end up here
 else
   // will never be here`

Answer (score 5):

Your problem seems to be in the statement `x = 1`, you should change by `x == 1`, cause asignment always will be true.

Hope this help!

Comment: Assignement will not always be true, for exemple x = 0 in a test is false.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one, to avoid mistyping `==` ;-) :

```
char randDirection()
{
    return "udlr"[rand() % 4];
};
```

Comment: That's far too clever to be useful. +1 anyway.

Comment: @MarkRansom  Sorry, I couldn't resist ;-) i should remind myself the famous quote of B.Kernighan: "*Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it*"

Comment: Wow, that's a really cool line of code. So it's treating the set of characters "udlr" as a sort of 4-element container?

Comment: @warranpenner thanks ! That's it. The litteral string is understood as a pointer, and i just index it like in an array